# Which image sharing websites supports file uploading dynamically via api

Tags: api, image-hosting

I have been searching for image hosting website that displays images of a user in a nice and managed way.

I want to upload the files to that image hosting website in my account of that website from a page in my website.

i.e if i have a website `abc.com` then user browse my website `abc.com`. Uploads the file to my website. Now I want to transfer the uploaded file to the image hosting website so that it can be viewed by other users of that hosting website and get better visibility to world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imgur does: http://api.imgur.com/

Comment: thnx.... i found http://imageshack.com also useful